# How to fix an argument error with the "BIOMOD_ModelingOptions()" function in R

Tags: r, geospatial, modeling, maxent

I have been using R code to predict the future distribution of small mammal species based on records of their occurrence in the Atlantic Forest and predictions of environmental variables. I used this code just fine throughout last year, but now it gives the following error:

```
Error in BIOMOD_ModelingOptions(MAXENT.Phillips = list(path_to_maxent.jar = "C:/Users/Isabella/Documents/R/library/dismo/java",  : 
  unused argument (MAXENT.Phillips = list(path_to_maxent.jar = "C:/Users/Isabella/Documents/R/library/dismo/java", memory_allocated = NULL, maximumiterations = 500, linear = T, quadratic = T, product = F, threshold = F, hinge = F, lq2lqptthreshold = 80, l2lqthreshold = 10, hingethreshold = 15, beta_threshold = -1, beta_categorical = -1, beta_lqp = -1, beta_hinge = -1, betamultiplier = 0.5, defaultprevalence = 0.5))
```

At first, I thought the error could be related to the value of `path_to_maxent.jar`.  I tried changing it, but the original path was correct.

A colleague of mine tried running the same code on her computer and did not see the error, but my computer runs Windows and hers does not.  She said it could be an update issue.  I already tried updating R and all of my R packages, but nothing worked.

What is the problem?

Comment: You could try naming the argument `MAXENT` (only) instead of `MAXENT.Phillips`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/biomod2/versions/4.2-2/topics/BIOMOD_ModelingOptions

Comment: That worked, thank you! But now when I move on to the next part of the code to run maxent and use BIOMOD_Modeling, it shows up the error "Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection". Do you know what it could be related to?

Comment: Judging from these search results, there's probably some parallel computation, or failed attempt to, interfering: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+Error+in+summary.connection%28connection%29 Hard to tell.